# Using Method.getReturnType() on overridden method

Tags: java, reflection, subclass

I have a class that needs to get the return type of a method, that has been overwritten by something else.

Say that I have a class like:

```
public class SuperDuperClass {
    public Object someMethod();
}
```

I then create a subclass:

```
public class DuperClass extends SuperDuperClass{
    public String someMethod();
}
```

I then get the `someMethod()` for DuperClass:

```
Method theMethod = DuperClass.class.getMethod("someMethod", new Class[]{});
Class theMethodReturnType = theMethod.getReturnType();
```

I would very much like the returnType to be String, as is defined in DuperClass. However, I receive Object, as defined in SuperDuperClass. It would seem reflection doesn't really care that the overriden method returns another type, so the supermethod type is returned.

Is there some what to get the return type of the subclass in this case?

I accept both voodoo, witchcraft and blood magic.

---

Ansver: I will post a real ansver when i am allowed.

The getMethods() method returns two someMethod instances. I am using getMethod, which, at least on my JVM, returns the superclass (Instead of the subclass).

Dumb me.

Comment: I've tested your example and got `java.lang.String`. So I don't understand what's the problem. Which version of java do you use?

Comment: Which java compiler? You could try `Class.getDeclaredMethod` first, and walk the inheritance upwards yourself. But I would suspect _every_ compiler to work with `getMethod`, so a bug, usage of generics or whatever.

Comment: You guys should stop downvoting before he answers to Andremoniy

Comment: java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: And if it just works for you, i can't exactly explain why. But it doesn't. I guess the problem isn't with the code then?

Comment: Indeed, `DuperClass.class.getMethods();` lists both methods. Please edit the question with this info; besides that I can't revoke my downvote before the question is edited.

Comment: I think @JoopEggen gave the answer. I have looked at the doc, and it appears that `Class.getDeclaredMethod` does not include inherited methods, whereas `Class.getMethod` do.

Comment: It does indeed return both methods when i use getMethods instead of getMethod. So it seems to be slightly random which one is returned first. Well.. Explained...

Comment: They say in the doc that the order is unspecified

Answer (score 3):

You are in a case of covariant return type.

You can find an explanation [here](https://dzone.com/articles/covariant-return-type-abyssal).

Comment: This would have given the answer; that both methods `Object someMethod()` and `String someMethod()` exist in the class. Next time explain it too; maybe with code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was simply this.

```
DuperClass.class.getMethod("someMethod", new Class[]{});
```

returns only one method. But actually, two methods exist with this signature. getMethods returns both a someMethod with "Object" return type, and one with "String" return type.

Which one is returned by getMethod does not seem to be entirely reliable.

Instead

```
DuperClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("someMethod", new Class[]{});
```

returns the correct Method.

Comment: Did you try using `getDeclaredMethod` as both of us adviced you ?

Comment: Yes, and i did not reflect that in the answer. Sorry about that.